# Perform sorting between two entities

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity `EventScheduleOnc` with an attribute `eventNameOnc` with one-to-one relationship with `EventDec` entity with an attribute `eventStatus`. I am trying to perform sort like this

```
 var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in 

    let eventsOncFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"EventScheduleOnc")
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"EventDec.eventStatus", ascending: true)
    let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"eventNameOnc", ascending: true)
    eventsOncFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor,secondarySortDescriptor]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: eventsOncFetchRequest, managedObjectContext:context,
                                         sectionNameKeyPath:"EventDec.eventStatus",cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self

    return frc}()
```

I am getting this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath EventDec.eventStatus
>   not found in entity '

Comment: In `"EventDec.eventStatus"` replace "EventDec" by the name of the relationship from EventScheduleOnc to EventDec.

Comment: @MartinR, Appreciate it, that works :)